# Find departments which hired also the same years as department 10 did. Suppose department 10 hires every year

Tags: sql, count, duplicates, db2, aggregate-functions

Hello I should find the  departments with the same hiredate as dept 10. I also have to use the **YEAR() function and aggregate functions**. The result table should look like this:

```
    deptnum  first    last   count
    -------------------------------
    10      1999      2000     2
    20      1999      2000     2
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT e.deptnum, YEAR(e.hiredate) AS first, YEAR (e.hiredate) AS last, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM emp AS e
WHERE e.deptnum IN (SELECT e.deptno
FROM emp AS e1
WHERE e.deptnum=10)
GROUP BY e.deptnum, YEAR(e.hiredate)
HAVING COUNT(e.deptnum)>1 ;
```

And this is the result table from my SQL:

```
    deptnum  first    last   count
    -------------------------------
    10      1999      1999     2
```

I'm getting confused how to get the right duplicates. Can somebody, please help me?

Comment: *find the departments with the same hiredate as dept 10*: a department does not have a `hiredate`, does it? So what does this sentence actually means?

Comment: even the first hiredate and last hiredate is common. I guess its a min and max date of hire

Answer (score 0):

You should compare year of each department with year of dept 10 as below via where as the comparision is deptwise not within the dept

```
   SELECT e.deptnum, YEAR(e.hiredate) 
 AS first, YEAR (e.hiredate) AS last, 
   COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM emp AS e
  WHERE YEAR(e.hiredate)  IN (SELECT  
    Year(e.hiredate)
    FROM emp AS e1
   WHERE e.deptnum=10) and 
  e.deptnum<>10
 GROUP BY e.deptnum, 
  YEAR(e.hiredate)
   HAVING COUNT(e.deptnum)>1 ;
```

Comment: Just tested it, but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: I get it because i forgot to add one condition in where that e. Deptname<>10 check now

Comment: This way I'm getting empty columns, I think because of the e.deptnum=10 and then not equal 10.

Comment: No, if you give deptname=10 in the outer query then theres no point of matching it with inner query having only deptname 10. Did you run the exact above query which i posted and why you have same columns as first and last as your tables data shows these are two different dates

Comment: Yes, I did run the exact query above, and I'm getting empty values, I tried MAX and MIN for the same columns, but still everything remains the same

Comment: Did the hiredate match with your deptname 10 hiredate check this first

Comment: Yes the years are matching.

Comment: Ohh you want 2 rows my goodness you want dept 10 as well then you could remove that e. Deptname<>10 and post your whole inpug data sample with drsired o/p

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH EMP (DEPTNUM, HIREDATE) AS 
(
-- Sample Data Block
-- You may replace it by your own SELECT statement
-- returning the same columns 
VALUES
  (10, DATE('2017-01-01'))
, (10, DATE('2017-01-01'))
, (10, DATE('2018-01-01'))
, (10, DATE('2019-01-01'))

, (11, DATE('2017-01-01'))
, (11, DATE('2017-01-01'))
, (11, DATE('2018-01-01'))
, (11, DATE('2018-01-01'))
, (11, DATE('2019-01-01'))

, (12, DATE('2016-01-01'))
, (12, DATE('2017-01-01'))
, (12, DATE('2018-01-01'))

, (13, DATE('2016-01-01'))
, (13, DATE('2017-01-01'))
, (13, DATE('2018-01-01'))
, (13, DATE('2019-01-01'))
-- End of Sample Data Block
)
, HIRE_YEAR AS 
(
-- All hiring years by department 
SELECT DISTINCT DEPTNUM, YEAR(HIREDATE) AS HIREYEAR
FROM EMP
)
, HIRE_CNT AS 
(
-- Count of hiring years by department
SELECT DEPTNUM, COUNT(1) AS YEAR_CNT
FROM HIRE_YEAR
GROUP BY DEPTNUM
)
, AGG AS 
(
-- Count of THE SAME hiring years for other departments
SELECT H.DEPTNUM, COUNT(1) AS COUNT
FROM HIRE_YEAR H10
JOIN HIRE_YEAR H ON H.DEPTNUM <> H10.DEPTNUM AND H.HIREYEAR = H10.HIREYEAR
WHERE H10.DEPTNUM = 10
GROUP BY H.DEPTNUM
)
-- Count of the same hiring years for a department 
-- must be equal to TOTAL COUNT:
-- for DEPTNUM = 10 
-- and for this DEPTNUM itself, if there is an additional requirement for this department 
-- to hire the same years ONLY as DEPTNUM = 10 (commented out below)   
SELECT A.*
FROM AGG A
JOIN HIRE_CNT H10 ON H10.DEPTNUM = 10 AND H10.YEAR_CNT = A.COUNT
--JOIN HIRE_CNT H ON H.DEPTNUM = A.DEPTNUM AND H.YEAR_CNT = A.COUNT 
;

|DEPTNUM    |COUNT      |
|-----------|-----------|
|11         |3          |
|13         |3          |
```

You may run this statement as is. It's possible to make any changes to the sample data to see how it affects the result.
`DEPTNUM = 13` is in the result set, because it has a superset of hiring years for `DEPTNUM = 10`.
If hiring years for another department must be exactly the same, just uncomment the last line.